# Python, avoid nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have one dataframe with values such as ('ABC' or 'BCD') and another list of dictionaries in this format [{ID: 'ABC', StList: ['ABC','BCD','DEF']},{ID: 'DEF', StList: ['ABC','CCC','DEF']}....]

`df = ['ABC' or 'BCD',.....]`

`dictList = [{ID: 'ABC', StList: ['ABC','BCD','DEF']},{ID: 'DEF', StList: 'ABC','CCC','DEF']}....]`

I have to iterate through the dataframe, checking each value in a column if it exists in StList - return ID if it is true, appending the ID to another list.

For this I have used nested loops which works but is not ideal - performance wise. Is there another way of approaching this?

Edit: Alternative I tried

`Df1 = ['ABC', 'ABC' or 'BCD', 'ZYB', ('ABC' and 'CD') or 'NMM']`

`DF2 =  [{ID:Testing, STList: ['ABC','BCD','ZYY','NMM'],{ID:Testing2, STList: ['ABC'].......}]`

For first row of DF1: 
Return result should be something like final_result = ['Testing','Testing2'] and then this will be updated in DF1 against first row.

Is there a way to achieve this using dataframe functionality - it has boolean logic in some rows that needs to be evaluated too?

Comment: Be more clear, please. You have to check every StList? Give us an example of return ID with that case you mentioned.

Comment: It would be easier to know what exactly you want to achieve if you provide your nested loop code, reading and understanding text is way harder than converting loops into some dataframe tricks

Comment: You’re talking about dataframes, does that mean you’re using pandas? In that case the pythonic solution would be to use pandas API with queries and selectors. This would remove loops altogether

Comment: you mention that performance is an issue here, whether you use nested loops or a single clever loop will likely not change the number of read operations you have to do. A loop in itself is not very expensive, its the number of total operations you are doing.  Unless you have something clever like data indexing going on, you really are just going to have to read every element of every StList and see if it's equal or not, nested logic or otherwise.  And anyways, your data structure is nested, might as well have the code reflect that fact for intuition's sake

Comment: #Convert the dictList into dictionary, then your search operation will take O(1) time

Comment: `'ABC' or 'BCD'` is just `True`. Is that really what's in your "dataframe"? Also, what is supposed to happen if a value is found in two `StList`s, like `ABC`, which `ID` do you return then? All of them? Obviously the dictionary should be "inverted", so that  the values in `df` are the keys, and the values are lists of the corresponding `ID`s. That makes this a simple dictionary lookup. The extra nesting in `dictList` looks pretty pointless, too.

Comment: I have just made an edit. I was just trying out ways to improve performance instead of iterating each row of dataframe 1 with dataframe 2 as some rows have boolean statements that are required to be evaluated. Also theres no duplicates in data.

Comment: Yes I am using pandas. I will update the tag in question too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is: NO

There is no possible approach to your inquiry which prevents nested loops to improve performance. In order to scan each of the data within the dictionaries/array it requires layers of iteration to reach the peak nodes of an index. You could manually find the specific element by using selectors(column&rows)/indexes but it's not applicable with your scenario.